# PowerBI Aggregating IDs

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I am using direct query to connect with a local database through PowerBI. However when I import, the IDs are being aggregated automatically when they should not. An example is the MonthID and Year as in the image attached. I also read on this issue, but I do not have the "not summarize" option. I am using PowerBI Desktop.  Any solution[image] for this please?

Also I am using PowerBI desktop as I cannot write DAX queries in powerbi.com. Although I will then publish the DAX powerbi desktop report on powerbi.com so as I can share it.

Adding on my question (after Leonard's reply). So I have tried to push a unit capacity value in a barchart. However, it still did not give me the option to 'Do not summarize' as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Don't summarize" option appears when you use the field in a visual. You can ignore the Σ symbol in the field list...all it really means is that the field is numeric (i.e. aggregatable); it doesn't mean that it has to be aggregated.

Try, for example, adding a table visual and adding Year. It may sum them to start with, but you should then be able to click on the down arrow and change to "Don't summarize"

[image: Don't summarize option]

If you add the field to the axis or legend of a visual, then it won't summarize anyway. The "Don't summarize" option only comes into play when it's ambiguous how you might want the field to be treated (such as in a table).

Comment: Hi Leonard thanks for your reply. I have tried what you suggested, however I still haven't managed to replicate what you are saying. I have edited the answer so as to show you the screenshot for me trying this.

Comment: The "values" section of a column chart requires an aggregated number, which is why it doesn't have the "Don't summarize" option. If you're trying to show the UnitCapacity for each individual unit, you would need to put something on the Axis to break the number down to the level you want (I'd suggest Unit Name, but from the screenshot it looks like all your unit names the same (i.e. blank), so it won't break the number down - perhaps a unit ID or something?)

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer Leonard. This solved my problem!

Comment: Leonard, i posted a question which continues on this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302007/powerbi-dynamic-time-series-barchart?noredirect=1#comment71758767_42302007. Would really appreciate your assistance